# AttributeError: type object 'cupy.core.core.broadcast' has no attribute '__reduce_cython__'

Tags: pycharm, windows-10, anaconda, conda, spacy

I got this error "AttributeError: type object 'cupy.core.core.broadcast' has no attribute '**reduce_cython**'" when I tried to run this command 'python -m spacy download en' on my PyCharm Terminal.

Here is the screenshot:
[image]

What I want is to download the English model for the purpose of using spaCy. But it failed since it said the type object 'cupy.core.core.broadcast' has no attribute '**reduce_cpython**'. Thanks a lot if there is anybody can help me to fix this problem.

Comment: https://docs-cupy.chainer.org/en/stable/install.html#requirements
Can you confirm you have all the requirements? Also have you followed this guide to install the library?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, because I installed a different version of Nvidia Cuda libraries and the one that came with spacy.

You can get the version with the command:

```
pip freeze | grep cupy
```

and the verion of cuda:

```
 nvcc --version
```

then you can install the correct library with

```
pip install -U spacy[cuda100]
```

(Use the version that corresponds to the Nvidia library: spacy[cuda], spacy[cuda90], spacy[cuda91] or spacy[cuda92])

https://spacy.io/usage/