# import modin.pandas causes ERROR: AttributeError: type object 'pyarrow.lib.Message' has no attribute '__reduce_cython__'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dask, modin

**Issue**

- I have installed `conda install -c conda-forge modin`
- When I import  `import modin.pandas as pd`
- I get an error message

**Tried solutions**

- Similar to but different framework, different use case and slightly different error message - [“has no attribute 'reduce_cython” error when using Pyinstaller exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57175603/has-no-attribute-reduce-cython-error-when-using-pyinstaller-exe)
- Not solved GitHub issue - https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/1953#issuecomment-398128940
- Different error code - [AttributeError: type object 'cupy.core.core.broadcast' has no attribute '__reduce_cython__'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53953623/attributeerror-type-object-cupy-core-core-broadcast-has-no-attribute-reduc)
- Different error code - [AttributeError: type object 'sklearn.manifold._barnes_hut_tsne.array' has no attribute '__reduce_cython__'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57258515/attributeerror-type-object-sklearn-manifold-barnes-hut-tsne-array-has-no-att)

**Error Message**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-f6aea802f5ba> in <module>
      2 import openpyxl
      3 
----> 4 import modin.pandas as pd
      5 ##import pandas as pd
      6 

~/anaconda3/envs/tfall/lib/python3.7/site-packages/modin/pandas/__init__.py in <module>
    170 
    171 from .. import __version__
--> 172 from .dataframe import DataFrame
    173 from .io import (
    174     read_csv,

~/anaconda3/envs/tfall/lib/python3.7/site-packages/modin/pandas/dataframe.py in <module>
     46 from .series import Series
     47 from .base import BasePandasDataset, _ATTRS_NO_LOOKUP
---> 48 from .groupby import DataFrameGroupBy
     49 from .accessor import CachedAccessor, SparseFrameAccessor
     50 

~/anaconda3/envs/tfall/lib/python3.7/site-packages/modin/pandas/groupby.py in <module>
     32     wrap_into_list,
     33 )
---> 34 from modin.backends.base.query_compiler import BaseQueryCompiler
     35 from modin.data_management.functions.default_methods.groupby_default import GroupBy
     36 from modin.config import IsExperimental

~/anaconda3/envs/tfall/lib/python3.7/site-packages/modin/backends/__init__.py in <module>
     17 __all__ = ["BaseQueryCompiler", "PandasQueryCompiler"]
     18 try:
---> 19     from .pyarrow import PyarrowQueryCompiler  # noqa: F401
     20 except ImportError:
     21     pass

~/anaconda3/envs/tfall/lib/python3.7/site-packages/modin/backends/pyarrow/__init__.py in <module>
     14 """The module represents the query compiler level for the PyArrow backend."""
     15 
---> 16 from .query_compiler import PyarrowQueryCompiler
     17 
     18 __all__ = ["PyarrowQueryCompiler"]

~/anaconda3/envs/tfall/lib/python3.7/site-packages/modin/backends/pyarrow/query_compiler.py in <module>
     26 from pandas.core.computation.ops import UnaryOp, BinOp, Term, MathCall, Constant
     27 
---> 28 import pyarrow as pa
     29 import pyarrow.gandiva as gandiva
     30 

~/anaconda3/envs/tfall/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyarrow/__init__.py in <module>
     52 
     53 
---> 54 from pyarrow.lib import cpu_count, set_cpu_count
     55 from pyarrow.lib import (null, bool_,
     56                          int8, int16, int32, int64,

~/anaconda3/envs/tfall/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyarrow/ipc.pxi in init pyarrow.lib()

AttributeError: type object 'pyarrow.lib.Message' has no attribute '__reduce_cython__'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[LINK](https://github.com/modin-project/modin/issues/4719#issuecomment-1196039768)

## Have not worked

The following gives me error:

1.code

```
conda create --name py37-install-4719 python=3.7
conda activate py37-install-4719
conda install modin modin-all modin-core modin-dask modin-omnisci modin-ray
```

1.output

RUNS for hours on a AWS ec2 g4dn.4xlarge with no other load I have monitored it with htop

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: |
```

## This have worked

Previously `pip install modin[all]` code might gave me an error because of:

- Maybe because I have used other python 3 version I think 3.9 other trials did not worked before this.
- I have also had the actual DASK package installed in other environments
- Any other library incompatibility

### Currently Fully working solution

```
conda create --name py37-install-4719-pip python=3.7
conda activate py37-install-4719-pip
pip install modin[all]
```

### Ex Code Usage

```
import modin.pandas as pd
from distributed import Client
client = Client()
df = pd.read_csv('my_single_csv_name.csv')
```